# What is the maximum x-axis range of acquired depth data in Google Project Tango?

Tags: google-project-tango

I need to divide the points based on their x-position, so that there is, for example, three divisions of points (a middle, left, and right). The middle one should have a range of one meter. Thus, I was wondering what is the min/max ranges of the x-axis?  is it large enough to add more divisions than three with same range (1 meter) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question is very precise. 
The x and y positions of the depth data will depend in the actual depth of the image. In particular, it will depend on the depth and the angle of the camera. If the wall in front of the camera is very close, there will be less x-axis range.

As an example. For a depth data with an average z-range of 1.5, I get a x-range around `[-0.8,0.8]`. For another frame, the average z-range is 3.0, the range goes to `[-1.6, 1.6]`. Of course these numbers depend on the scene itself, it was just to give you a little idea.

Is it clearer now?

Comment: Thank you @DanielGL for answering, it really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Horizontal field of View up to this equation

`Horizontal FOV = 2 * atan(0.5 * width / Fx)`

https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/intrinsics-extrinsics

In the Tango yellowstone is about 63 degrees. So it means that you have 31 degrees to left and 31 degrees to right.

Now, if you have pointcloudData based on xyz you can know that if z = 1 meter then you could apply trigonometry